# Output ASCII Value C++

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

If I have a char which holds a hex value such has 0x53, (S), how can I display this as "S"?

Code:

```
char test = 0x53;
cout << test << endl;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I don't understand... is there a question?

Comment: I am getting werid letters like ^@

Comment: What compiler / platform are you using? It should just display an S...

Comment: Im using gcc when I do cout << "test: " << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)test << endl; I get 53

Comment: don't cast it to an int, just leave it as a char and you should see an S. The cod you have above should just print an S.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as a variable that stores a hex value, or a decimal or octal value. Hex, octal, and decimal are just different ways of representing numbers to the compiler. The compiled code will represent everything in binary.

These statements all have the **exact** same effect (assuming the charset is ASCII):

```
test = 0x53; // hex
test = 'S';  // literal constant
test = 83;   // decimal
test = 0123; // octal
```

So print the character the same way you would with any character, no matter how you assign it a value.

Comment: Your first statement is a too strong.  Bob's test does hold a hex value; that hex value is 0x53.  Granted, it also holds decimal 83 and octal 0123, but it does hold 0x53 too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following, you have already answered your question:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char test = 0x53;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're calling the std namespace, why are you prefixing "cout" and "endl" with "std::"? seems a little redundant to me.

Comment: sorry my mistake in using the std:: again after calling the std namespace. just a matter of habit :(